# Creating a line from point data

Tags: arcgis-desktop, points-to-line

I have added coordinates into a excel sheet and converted them into .csv file (a short snip is shown below). these are transects therefore 'SOL' = Start of line' and 'EOL' = 'End of Line'. I have then uploaded this file into ArcGIS version 10.7 in ED50, UTM Zone 31 N.

[image]

This data has uploaded into ArcMaps fine and the results look like so (see below).

[image]

As you can see there is a clear SOL and EOL for each transect. I then use the 'Search tool' and select 'points to line (Data Management tool)'. I have uploaded the relevant layer and clicked 'ok'

[image]

The issue I get is that ArcGIS runs this request and plots a continuous line between all transect (see below).

[image]

What I require is just a line between each transect, not a continuous line, as seen below (shown as the blue pen).
[image]

Comment: Can you post the data points as text/code?  A picture of data is not very motivating for someone who wants to use your data in an answer.

Answer (score 1):

It is a perfect candidate for "Points to Line" tool with Transect field being a line id. Unfortunately author of this csv file invested significant efforts when merging pairs of Transect cells in Excel. This messed up otherwise nice database table.

Thus you need to recalculate Transect. So export your points to file database
[image]

and recalculate it using:

```
(!OBJECTID!-1)//2
```

Points in the picture below labelled by this value:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I apologize, but I do not have Arcgis-desktop (I'll continue to look for a solution). However, in QGIS 3.16 you can use the SAGA `convert points to line(s)` tool and specify the `Order by...` and `Separate by...` to give you your desired outputs.

Another method you could use in QGIS is the `points to path`. Check out this [post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/377129/create-lines-of-based-on-same-id-points) for more information.

**Edits:**

For your Arcgis-desktop solution, I'd take a look at using the `XY to Line Tool`. Check out the [support page](https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000012092) from ESRI. Also take a look at this [post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/272489/arcmap-create-lines-from-points-based-on-from-to-relation).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to set the "Line Field" parameter in the tool. Each line feature in the output will be based on unique values in the "Line Field".

In your case, you should set it to "Transect/Station" field.